# How to connect to Informix Database in python2.7.15?

Tags: python, informix

Should I configure any environment variables ? I am trying to connect through python .(not python3 )

Comment: Please kindly use your comments on the answer proposal of jsagrera to enhance the question instead. This way more people might be able to help you with even less effort.

Answer (score 3):

Try IfxPy from https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy
It supports Python 2.7 and Python 3

Comment: This is the code I am using import pypyodbc
print("This line will be printed.")  
conn = pypyodbc.connect(
    driver='iclit09b.dylib',
    server='xxxxxxx', 
    db='your_database',
    uid='xxxxx',
    pwd='xxxxxxx') 
print('connection to the database is established!!')

Comment: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ifxpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ifxpy